# How to atomically make Arc<> delete an AtomicPtr

Tags: rust

So in rust, I want to have an atomically referenced count pointer, but I want that pointer to also be atomic. Meaning that for whatever pointer the Arc holds, it will free the memory pointed to by the pointer when the reference count is zero.

Say I have the following code in C++

```c++
template<class T>
class AtomicShared {
public:
    AtomicShared(): _ptr(nullptr), _counter(nullptr) 
                     {}
    AtomicShared(T* ptr): _ptr(ptr),
                           _counter(new std::atomic<size_t>(1))
                     {}
    
    AtomicShared(const AtomicShared<T>& other) {
        _counter.store(other._counter.load());
        _counter.load()->fetch_add(1);
        _ptr.store(other._ptr.load());
    }
    
    AtomicShared<T>& operator=(const AtomicShared<T>& other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other) {
            if (_counter.load() != nullptr && _counter.load()->fetch_sub(1) == 1) {
                delete _ptr.load();
                delete _counter.load();         
            }
            _counter.store(other._counter.load());
            _counter.load()->fetch_add(1);
            _ptr.store(other._ptr.load());
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    bool cmp_exchange(T* expected, T* desired = nullptr) {
        if (_ptr.compare_exchange_strong(expected, desired)) {
            if (_counter.load()->fetch_sub(1) == 1) {
                delete expected;
                delete _counter.load();
            }
            _counter.store(new std::atomic<size_t>(1));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    ~AtomicShared() {
        if (_counter.load()->fetch_sub(1) == 1) {
            delete _ptr.load();
            _ptr.store(nullptr);
            delete _counter.load();
        }
    }
private:
    std::atomic<T*> _ptr;
    std::atomic<std::atomic<size_t>*> _counter;
};
```

For rust, I want to be able to have an equivalent of this code that with an `Arc<AtomicPtr<foo>>` can:

1. Support CAS aka `compare_exchange` on the pointer (is already supported by `AtomicPtr`)
2. Can delete the `AtomicPtr` contained in the `Arc` when the `Arc<>` reference count goes to zero. Assume the `AtomicPtr` contains some heap allocated pointer that could have been CAS'd into it.

Im not sure how to accomplish 2. This is intended to be used for some lock/wait free project that I am trying to do in Rust instead of C++.

---

I came to the following code to solve this issue

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
                                      
struct PtrGuard<T> {
    ptr: AtomicPtr<T>
}

impl<T> Drop for PtrGuard<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
   let a = Arc::new(PtrGuard{ptr:AtomicPtr::new(Box::into_raw(Box::new(AtomicUsize::new(1))))});
   let got = a.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
   unsafe {
       println!("got {}", <*const AtomicUsize>::as_ref(got).unwrap().load(Ordering::SeqCst));
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into [`AtomicCell`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.0/crossbeam/atomic/struct.AtomicCell.html) which provides lock-free swapping etc of atomic-sized data without unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to do manual deallocation or cleanup (are you using `unsafe` for allocation?), you don't need to to anything special. When the last `Arc` is dropped, it will call `drop` on the `AtomicPtr`. If you do need do to manual deallocation/cleanup, I think you could solve this by using making a struct `PtrGuard<T>(pub AtomicPtr<T>>)` that implements `Drop` (running your custom cleanup code), and your smart pointer type will be `Arc<PtrGuard<T>>`.

Comment: The allocation would be consuming a Box pointer or unsafe yes.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein I just updated the code at the end. The smart pointer type I wrote was wrong.